# Get vector length with GLM

Tags: c++, vectors, glm

I am quite confused over how GLM library is behaving or I am using it improperly.

```
glm::vec2 testVec(6,-4);

float len = testVec.length();
```

I get the value `2` with the above code snippet. I believe I am trying to get the length of the vector defined by `testVec`. You know very well that it is not the correct length of the vector. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 26):

Sorry folks for posting such a trivial issue! The issue is solved. I was using the wrong function. Here goes the correct one:

```
glm::vec2 testVec(6,-4);
float len  = glm::length(testVec);
```

The member function of the same name returns the number of components instead (i.e. `vec2::length` will always yield `2`, `vec3::length` will always yield `3`, etc.).

Comment: Don't apologise, I think it's a fair question, seeing that GLM's function naming is quite misleading here. I expect this could be a useful (and concise) reference in the future.

Comment: @MartinEnder it's not GLM who's guilty: the GLSL spec prescribes this confusion to exist: there's `length(vecN)` free function returning the norm of `vecN`, and `vecN.length()` method, returning dimension of `vecN`. See §5.5 _Vector and Scalar Components and Length_ of GLSL 4.60 spec.

Comment: You are not alone.

Comment: I too am a member of the "Wrong Length Function Anonymous" group.